# От чего зависит выбор окончания в причастии?

Tags: согласование, причастия, окончания

У меня с товарищем возник спор: нужно написать рапорт, но в образце, как я заметил, написано неправильно окончание, и я не могу доказать ему это. Решил обратиться к специалистам, чтобы доказать, что я прав. Предложение такое:

> Прошу Вас выплатить материальную помощь за 2019 год,
>   предусмотренн("ой" или "ую") приказом Министра обороны Российской
>   Федерации.

Вопрос: какое окончание пишется в слове **"предусмотренн("ую" или "ой")**? Как я знаю, это причастный оборот, и слово **предусмотренную** относится к слову **помощь**, поэтому окончание должно быть **"ую"**.
Ответьте, пожалуйста, чтобы он мне поверил, может я не прав в чем-то.

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2):

Ваши рассуждения правильны.

Слово [предусмотренный](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) — это причастие (особая  форма  глагола,  которая  обозначает 
признак  предмета  по  действию, отвечает  на  вопросы *какой?  какая?  какое?  какие?* и совмещает  в  себе  признаки  глагола  и  прилагательного).

В  предложениях  причастия  обычно  **согласуются  с  именами существительными**  и  выступают  в  роли  определения; как  и  прилагательные,  **изменяются  по  падежам, числам и родам.**

*Прошу Вас выплатить* (что? В. п.) *материальн**ую помощь*** (ж. р., ед. ч.) *за 2019 год,* (какую? В. п.) *предусмотренн**ую** приказом...*

[**Причастие**](https://school-assistant.ru/?predmet=russian&theme=prichastie_kak_osobaja_forma_glagola)

Answer (score 1):

Верно:

> Прошу Вас выплатить материальную помощь за 2019 год, предусмотренн**ую** приказом Министра обороны Российской Федерации.

Дело в том, что причастие *предусмотренную* согласуется (т. е. зависит) с существительным женского рода *помощь*, стоящим в **винительном** падеже. Это значит, что и причастие должно быть женского рода и в винительном падеже. Окончание -ой, которое предлагается, не подходит, потому что оно указывает на родительный падеж.